# Batch: Replacement for goto loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

When I'm writing batch programs I tend to create a goto loop to set and display things.

Example:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:loop
if !num! GTR !max!
set /a "num=num+1"
echo display!num! = !display%num%!
goto :loop
```

I had a feeling that I can replace this with a for loop, but I had no success creating one that can replace the loop above. Does anyone know?

Comment: if it's just displaying all `display<n>` (without doing something else), `set display` should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for /L` loop.

```
for /L %%A in (!num!,1,!max!) do echo display%%A = !display%%A!
```

Where `!num!` is your starting number, `!max!` is your ending number, and `1` means count up by ones.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Set limits
    set /a "num=1", "max=10"

    rem Prepare a set of variables to test
    for /l %%a in (%num% 1 %max%) do set "display%%a=!random!"

    rem Show the variables contents
    for /l %%a in (%num% 1 %max%) do echo display%%a=!display%%a!
```